# Adicionar valor inicial a uma lista ligada

Tags: c

Boa noite. Estou a implementar uma lista ligada e queria fazer uma função para adicionar ao fim da lista um elemento, nessa função queria verificar se a lista está vazia e em caso afirmativo adicionar o primeiro elemento à lista mas não estou a conseguir.

Definição do nó e macros

```
#define VALUE(p) ((p) -> value)
#define NXT(p) ((p) -> nxt)

typedef struct node{
    int value;
    struct node *nxt;
}NODE;
```

Criação de um novo nó

```
    NODE * new_node (int v, NODE *prox){
        NODE *l= (NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));

        VALUE(l)= v;
        NXT(l) = prox;
}
```

Função para adicionar elementos no fim da lista

```
NODE *add_last(int x, NODE *l){ 

    NODE *curr=l;

    if(l==NULL){
        NODE *aux = new_node(x, l);
        l=aux;
        return l;
    }


    while(NXT(curr)!=NULL){
        curr=NXT(curr);
    }

    NXT(curr)= new_node (x, NULL);
    return l;
}
```

Função Main

```
int main(){
    NODE *lista=NULL;
    add_last(6, lista);
}
```

Se alguém me conseguir ajudar agradeço.
Melhores cumprimentos

Comment: A sua função `new_node` não cria um nó com `malloc` e utiliza o valor `l` que não existe. A sua função `add_last` retorna a lista mas você não a usa no `main`. E as macros que definiu no inicio são estranhas e acabam por não ser úteis pois escondem a notação dos ponteiros que ajuda a perceber o tipo de cada variável no código.

Comment: Por lapso não tinha colocado a linha do código que usa o malloc, já corrigi. Em relação às macros foi a professora da cadeira que recomendou usar. Em relação a não usar a a lista no main, quer dizer que tenho de fazer lista=add_last?. Desde já obrigado

Comment: Estou confuso porque se eu no main fizer lista=new_node() as chamadas a add_last funcionam sem problema, no entanto eu no add_last queria criar o primeiro elemento da lista caso a lista ainda não tivesse elementos e é isso que não estou a conseguir fazer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Falta o retorno na função de criação do nó:

```
NODE * new_node (int v, NODE *prox) {
    NODE *l= (NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));

    VALUE(l)= v;
    NXT(l) = prox;

    return l; //<-- este
}
```

E no `main` falta utilizar a lista que é retornada na função `add_last`:

```
int main() {
    NODE *lista=NULL;
    lista = add_last(6, lista);
//  ^^^^^^^
}
```

Sem isto a sua função devolve uma nova lista quando está vazia, mas você não a utiliza, e por isso é como se nunca tivesse adicionado. Só iria funcionar corretamente no caso em que já tivesse elementos.

[Veja a funcionar no Ideone](https://ideone.com/2f4KDQ)

Comment: Obrigado já está a funcionar

Comment: @FabioSilva Sem problema, estamos cá para ajudar